I tried create -n virtual environment with anaconda: An unexpected error has occurred
I want to make virtual environment. I installed powershell, anaconda, jupyter etc. and I set evironment variable. but I can't make virtual environment with anaconda help me. I studying python - practice the web crawling. so I should make virtual env. I tried "conda -n test python=3.7 anaconda" and failed
I entered "$ C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py create -n crawling python=3.7" so then
  environment variables:
             CIO_TEST=<not set>
    CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
            CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
           CONDA_EXES="C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
         CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\beads\anaconda3
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\python.exe
           CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\beads\anaconda3
          CONDA_SHLVL=1
       CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
             HOMEPATH=\Users\beads
           LD_PRELOAD=<not set>
                 PATH=C:\Users\beads\anaconda3;C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\Library\mingw-
                      w64\bin;C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\beads\anacon
                      da3\Library\bin;C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\beads\anacon
                      da3\bin;C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\condabin;"C:\Program
                      Files\Java\jdk-11\bin; C:\Program Files\Common
                      Files\Oracle\Java\javapath";C:\Program
                      Files\Java\jdk-11\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
                      Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Users\beads\AppData\Local\Progr
                      ams\Python\Python37\Scripts;C:\Users\beads\AppData\Local\Programs\Pyth
                      on\Python37;C:\Users\beads\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\User
                      s\beads\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\beads\AppData\Local\P
                      rograms\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\beads\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Wi
                      ndows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:
                      \Users\beads\anaconda3;C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\Library;C:\Users\beads
                      \anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-
                      11\bin;C:\Users\beads\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\bea
                      ds\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\beads\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft
                      VS Code\bin;C:\Users\beads\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program
                      Files\nodejs;C:\Users\beads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scr
                      ipts;C:\Users\beads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37;C:\Program
                      Files (x86)\Java\jre-1.8;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community
                      Edition 2023.3.4\bin;.;C:\Program
                      Files\Java\jdk-11\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;.
         PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                      PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
   REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
        SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\Library\ssl\cacert.pem

 active environment : base
active env location : C:\Users\beads\anaconda3
        shell level : 1
   user config file : C:\Users\beads\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\beads\.condarc
      conda version : 23.7.4
conda-build version : 3.26.1
     python version : 3.11.5.final.0
   virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                      __win=0=0
   base environment : C:\Users\beads\anaconda3  (writable)
  conda av data dir : C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
       channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
      package cache : C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\pkgs
                      C:\Users\beads\.conda\pkgs
                      C:\Users\beads\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
   envs directories : C:\Users\beads\anaconda3\envs
                      C:\Users\beads\.conda\envs
                      C:\Users\beads\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
           platform : win-64
         user-agent : conda/23.7.4 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.11.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19045
      administrator : False
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If you suspect this error is being caused by a malfunctioning plugin,
consider using the --no-plugins option to turn off plugins.

Example: conda --no-plugins install <package>

Alternatively, you can set the CONDA_NO_PLUGINS environment variable on
the command line to run the command without plugins enabled.

Example: CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install <package>


Have you tried the solution it provided? conda --no-plugins install <package>
